# swapping 2 terms in a numpy array, python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

old_order=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
new_order=old_order
swap_1,swap_2=random.sample(range(0,9),2)
new_order[swap_1],new_order[swap_2]=old_order[swap_2],old_order[swap_1]

print(old_order,new_order)
```

So I am trying to swap two random element within an array. old_order would be the original array and new_order would be the array after the switch happened. What I don't understand is that why would the values of the old_order be changed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34na2.png)

I have narrow down the problem to

```
new_order[swap_1],new_order[swap_2]=old_order[swap_2],old_order[swap_1]
```

If this line is remove, both new order and old order will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one array.  `old_order` and `new_order` are both bound to the same array.  This line

```
new_array = old_array
```

makes a new reference.  It doesn't make a copy of the data.  If you really need a copy, use `old_order.copy()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been scratching my head for like an hour

Answer (score 0):

```
new_order=old_order.copy()
```

Create a new array for new_order.
Otherwise new_order, old_order take the same memory.